# Swagger document for spring security using xml configuration

Tags: xml, spring-security, swagger

I  tried using swagger, spring-rest-doc and spring-fox to generate documentation for spring mvc based rest services.  However, my challenge is to document spring security xml configuration based endpoints.  So far spring-fox has been the winner.  But it documents all of the methods that spring security supports.  Any ideas on how to filter out the ones I need?

For instance, when I use /swagger-ui.html to pull up the documentation page
I see the following groups:

- basic-error-controller
- authorization-endpoint
- whitelabel-approval-endpoint
- health-checker

Of which I only need authorization-endpoint and health-checker.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the documentation [to transition to 2.0](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/docs/transitioning-to-v2.md)?

```js
@Bean
public Docket swaggerSpringMvcPlugin() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .groupName("business-api")
        .select() 
           //Ignores controllers annotated with @CustomIgnore
          .apis(not(withClassAnnotation(CustomIgnore.class)) 
          // and by paths
          .paths(paths()) 
          .build()
        .apiInfo(apiInfo())
        .securitySchemes(securitySchemes())
        .securityContext(securityContext());
}
```

You should be able to use the RequestHandlerSelectors to filter the apis you need 
using the following predicates

- class annotations like the example show above `withClassAnnotation`
- method annotations (for filtering operations) `withMethodAnnotation`
- by base package `basePackage`

I suspect you've already figured out how to get it to work with xml configuration (in which case the title of this question is incorrect). In case you need more examples there is also plenty of [demos and examples](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-demos). If you have any more questions, the issue tracker is probably a better place than stackoverflow.com which we dont frequent as often.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I reached out on another forum and you answered (thanks).  The problem is that the tokenendpoint in spring (2.0.5) exposes the endpoint /oauth/token to all http methods.  Can't figure out how to filter out specific methods.

Comment: This `.apis(not(withClassAnnotation(CustomIgnore.class)) ` does not work for me with 2.2.2.

Comment: @MikhailBatcer `@ApiIgnore` is already supported. The `not(....)` technique is only if you don't want to use the annotation springfox provides . In any case please do create an issue if it doesn't work.